# Special character with full text search

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have one table with one column (Description)

Data is here:
 description = 12/23,12,43,sd,24,23

When I search this record with full text search

```
select * from ProductSearch WHERE FREETEXT(description, '12/23')
```

Then it gives result like (12/23,12,23)

It assumes 12/23 as separate words (12 and 23).

But I want to search one result like  12/23

how we can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select * from ProductSearch WHERE FREETEXT(description, '"12/23"')
```

This might help.